# managing wallet from ubuntu/linux

Tags: wallet, full-node, linux

the whole point of cryptocurrency is to be decentralized, so I would like to manage a wallet from my computer (ubuntu 20.04) without relying on a provider (e.g. binance).

I would like to use my wallet freely:

- selling, buying, trading and cashing out however I want
- mining whatever I want whenever I feel like doing it

How would I do that? I'm less of a beginner and I really could use some advice

Answer (score 1):

To manage your own wallet independently without trusting anyone else, you can download and run Bitcoin Core. This is a full node software that will download and validate the entire blockchain and allow you to create encrypted wallets on your own computer.

To get started with Bitcoin Core, you can either download it from [bitcoincore.org](https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/) or
compile it directly from the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md).

> mining whatever I want whenever I feel like doing it

Mining on a personal computer is completely infeasible now. The cost of electricity and wear-and-tear on your hardware will vastly outweigh any small reward you might obtain from mining. To have any hope of mining bitcoin, you need dedicated hardware (called ASICs).

Comment: Dearest, thank you for your answer. I don't pay electricity here (and I won't for at least one year), but my point is to start doing it. How should I go for it? How would I cash out?

Comment: It would be better to mine other coins rather than Bitcoin if you're going to use a PC.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of ETH, but HOW?

Comment: Questions about ethereum are off-topic on Bitcoin.SE. You could try asking on the [Ethereum StackExchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/).